# Charts using data from CiviCRM to show on Drupal website

Tags: drupal, chart

Is it possible for a chart to be created from data on the CiviCRM side and show on the website (drupal) portion?

For example, we would like to have a graph that live updates how much of our grant has been paid out and to what category.

Comment: Hey Laura - if you got this working with Charts module - can you please add an img to show us what it looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about pulling your grant data into a Drupal View and then using Charts and Google Charts module to display them?

Answer (score 3):

There is also Civisualize, a data visiualisation extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civisualize-missing-data-visualization-extension

And you could also use external tools for data visualisation, in one project I have worked with Apache Zeppelin as data visualisation: https://zeppelin.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just as an update to how it looks. Using Webform with the Google Charts module.

Comment: Interesting - hadn't thought of combining Webform results with Google Charts before. nice work

Comment: That looks awesome Laura!